# Application Support Syntax Error

Tags: compilation, applescript

I am trying to run a do shell script "osacompile (etc.)" in applescript. When I run osacompile (which will compile and export an applescript application), I get an error. This is what I have:

```
set SCRIPTTOCOMPILE to "
set pathtoopen to \"/Users/erictsai/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/\"
do shell script \"open \" & pathtoopen

do shell script "osacompile -x -o ~/Desktop/Script.app -e " & quoted form of SCRIPTTOCOMPILE
```

how come this won't work?

Comment: "An error"?. Please [edit] your question with the actual error message you're getting. Always do that when you report problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You'll see that you needed a quote after pathtoopen because SCRIPTTOCOMPILE needs to be a string. You're not trying to expand pathtoopen at that point, you want the word pathtoopen in the string.

Plus note that I added "quoted form of" to the command because you'll need to quote pathtoopen because it has a space in the path. Otherwise when you run the compiled script it will error. Good luck.

```
set SCRIPTTOCOMPILE to "set pathtoopen to \"/Users/erictsai/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/\"
do shell script \"open \" & quoted form of pathtoopen"

do shell script "osacompile -x -o ~/Desktop/Script.app -e " & quoted form of SCRIPTTOCOMPILE
```